# Can I rewrite a question that didn't benefit from migration?

Tags: discussion, migration

I wrote the following question on bicycles.SE:

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14971/should-cyclists-use-weight-training-to-strengthen-underutilized-muscles

A moderator encouraged me to flag it for migration to fitness.SE, which I did, but I'm a little disappointed with how it's turning out there. From this and other questions, I feel like it's more about weightlifting than fitness in general.

So my question is, can I rewrite my question for bicycles.SE, which I feel is a more relevant community?

I would be willing to change the wording to more fully emphasize the injury/safety aspect, which might make it more clear that it's more relevant for the cycling community than for the weightlifting community. But I want to make sure to do everything in the right way.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that you're definitely welcome to try, but given the nature of the question I'm not sure how you'd go about it.

I would also recommend exercising a little patience with the Fitness SE site. It's still a beta version and is still in the process of building a community.

It's also worth pointing out that cross-training is typically recommended for the winter months when cycling is less of a priority. Unless you're living in Australia or South America, your cycling season is just beginning and you're probably better off waiting a while to cross train anyway. If it were me, I'd try to build up a little rep over on Fitness SE and then offer a bounty on that question about October or November to renew interest in it.